# What's the best way to iterate through all combinations of a multi-dimensional array of unknown sizes without repeating any combination?

Tags: java, algorithm, multidimensional-array

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>> one = new ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>();
```

`one` would look something like this with some example values:

```
[  
    [  
        ["A","B","C",...],
        ["G","E","J",...],  
        ...  
    ],
    [ 
        ["1","2",...],
        ["8","5","12","7",...],  
        ...   
    ],  
    ... 
]
```

Assuming that there will always be one base case, at least one letter arraylist (e.g. ["A","B","C"]), but there could be more (e.g. ["X,"Y","Z"]) and there may be any size of number arraylists, maybe none at all, but could be hundreds (e.g. ["1","2","3"],...,["997","998","999"]). Also, there could be more types of arraylists (e.g. ["@","#","$"]) of any size. So really the only thing that is definitive is that ALWAYS:

```
one.size()>=1  
one.get(0).size()>=1  
one.get(0).get(0).size()>=1
```

So the problem is: How can I best get every combination of each category without knowing how large each arraylist will be or having any repeats but assuming that one.get(0).get(0) is valid? e.g. `["A","B","C",...] ["1","2",...] ...`, `["A","B","C",...] ["8","5","12","7",...] ...`. I'm using Java in my project currently but an any algorithm that works I can convert over myself. I apologize if this is not clear, I'm having a hard time putting it into words which is probably part of why I can't think of a solution.

Comment: Are you trying to make a spreadsheet program? What's the larger context, and where are you getting these arrays from that you don't know the dimension or size?

Comment: If it is a fixed depth then you just need to do simple loops. If you have variable depth the easiest solution is recursion.

Comment: So, given your example data structure, what is the exact output desired? Can you edit that into your post.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868914/how-to-get-2d-array-possible-combinations/15869610

Comment: If you can declare this: `ArrayList<ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>>` that means you know the dimension of the array, in this case it is three dimensional array of string, correct me if I am wrong. And what do you mean by all combination? For input 3d array like: `[a, b][1, 2, 3][x, y]` are you trying to produce this type of output: `a1x, a1y, b1x, b1y, a2x, a2y....`?

Comment: Thanks Patashu! You're correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two solutions to this, the recursive and the non recursive. Here's the non recursive (similar to the answer at [How to get 2D array possible combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868914/how-to-get-2d-array-possible-combinations/15869610) )

1) Multiply the length of every array together. This is the number of possible combinations you can make. Call this `totalcombinations`.

2) Set up an int[] array called `counters`. It should be as long as the number of arrays, and all initialized to 0.

3a) For `totalcombinations` times, concatenate `counter[0]`th entry in `arrays[0]`, the `counter[1]`th entry in `arrays[1]`... etc and add it to the list of all results.

3b) Then set `j = 0` and increment `counters[j]`. If this causes `counters[j] > arrays[j].length`, then `counters[j] = 0`, `++j` and increment the new `counters[j]` (e.g. repeat 3b)) until you do not get such an overflow.

If you imagine `counters` as being like the tumblers of a suitcase - when you overflow the first digit from 9 to 0, the next one ticks over - then you should get the strategy here.

Comment: What is `arrays` in this case? Is this array a new array or the same as the example `one` 3D arraylist given above?

Comment: @Bradley Oesch Yeah, it would be `one`. Also see the answer I linked to in the comments on your question for a similar solution to a similar problem

Comment: Yeah I just finished implementing the algorithm and it seems to work. I'll mark your answer as correct, but maybe you should also add the link to this answer so the correct answer has the algorithm I used. Thanks!