# Java nested list combination by stream without duplication

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, combinations

I want to generate all combination of group:item without item duplication in combination.
I prefer solution with java 8 stream. Actually I have a solution with "for" but its too memory intensive and for big array it fail. I tested it with group 5, items 61.

[my actual solution based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868914/how-to-get-2d-array-possible-combinations)

I can use 2d array of item groupItem[group][item] if its better, or nested list like bellow.

The purpose of this is to get the best price by combinating item by different group.

```
groupItem[][] itemss = {
{
        new groupItem().setGroup(1).setItem(1),
        new groupItem().setGroup(1).setItem(2),
        new groupItem().setGroup(1).setItem(3),
        new groupItem().setGroup(1).setItem(4)
},{
        new groupItem().setGroup(2).setItem(1),
        new groupItem().setGroup(2).setItem(2),
        new groupItem().setGroup(2).setItem(3),
        new groupItem().setGroup(2).setItem(4)
},{
        new groupItem().setGroup(3).setItem(1),
        new groupItem().setGroup(3).setItem(2),
        new groupItem().setGroup(3).setItem(3),
        new groupItem().setGroup(3).setItem(4)
}};

class groupItem {
    private int group;
    private int item;
    private double price;

    public int getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
    public groupItem setGroup(int group) {
        this.group = group;
        return this;
    }
    public int getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public groupItem setItem(int item) {
        this.item = item;
        return this;
    }
}
```

My actual code:

```
private List<List<groupItem>> combine(groupItem[][] matrix) {
    long sizeArray[] = new long[matrix.length];
    int counterArray[] = new int[matrix.length];
    int total = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
        sizeArray[i] = matrix[i].length;
        if(total * matrix[i].length == 0)
            break;
        total *= matrix[i].length;
    }

    List<List<groupItem>> items = new ArrayList<>(total);
    for (int count = total; count > 0; --count) {
        List<groupItem> sum = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
            sum.add(matrix[i][counterArray[i]]);
        }
        items.add(sum);
        for (int incIndex = matrix.length - 1; incIndex >= 0; --incIndex) {
            if (counterArray[incIndex] + 1 < sizeArray[incIndex]) {
                ++counterArray[incIndex];
                break;
            }
            counterArray[incIndex] = 0;
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Expected output

```
[1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 1:4]
[1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 2:4]
[1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 3:4]
[1:1, 1:2, 1:3, 4:4]
[1:1, 1:2, 2:3, 1:4]
[1:1, 1:2, 2:3, 2:4]
[1:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4] ....
```

**EDIT:** Can you help me to speed up this code, or rewrite it to stream, because for bigger array (60^5) it fail.

Thank you.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. This isn't a site for writing your code, but for answering questions. So... Ask a question that doesn't involve actually writing your code for you.

Comment: Edited my question with my actual code, and a question at the end. Thank you for warn me.